# Serial communication inside a custom library

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I made a custom library to communicate with my own board. The codes in library work but when i call the library itself i get an error.

I assumed the library is not working, so i put a print function in the library. It seems, that function works and the functions with serial communication are the problem.

I checked the communication code by itself but it works each time. Assuming there are some things to handle when using serial in a custom library, which i dont know any.

**iDealibrary.py**

```
import serial
import time

ser=serial.Serial('COM5',9600)

def ConnectIdeaLab():
    ser.sendBreak()
    a=ser.read()
    b=ser.read()
    if(a==b'O' and b ==b'K' ):
        ser.write(b'b')
        ser.write(b'b')
        ser.write(b'b')
        ser.write(b'a')
        ser.write(b'a')
        c=ser.read()
        if(c==b'!'):
            ser.write(bytes([3]))
            print("iDeaLab Moduna Girildi!")
            time.sleep(0.005)
            ser.sendBreak()

#this is the connection function. 

def printanything(parametre):
    print("writing: ",parametre)

#this is the print function to check if library is working.
```

**example.py**

```
import iDealibrary

iDealibrary.ConnectIdeaLab()
iDealibrary.printanything("selam")

#this does not work
```

I expect the last code to connect and print `iDealab moduna girildi`. Instead, i get

```
raise SerialException("ClearCommError failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
```

Comment: Please post the entire error with traceback, not just the line that it occurs on

Comment: If I had to make an educated guess, you never closed the port object you were testing with in the command line.

Comment: sorry for idiotic questions(a real newbie here) i did not understand what you suggested. should i close the serial comm like ser.close()

Comment: Also realized a new thing. when i opened spyder for the first time and try to example code, it works. i turn off and turn off my hardware but it does not work a second time. Saying this because it may support your theory.

Comment: as your reply about traceback. is it ok?
  File "D:\Users\Doguhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 273, in read
    raise SerialException("ClearCommError failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))

SerialException: ClearCommError failed (PermissionError(13, 'Aygıt komutu algılayamıyor.', None, 22))

Comment: Post it in the question, so it's legible.

Comment: I've been working with ports a long time. First thing to check is always if the port is open elsewhere. The important thing there is the permission error, which means yes. Get in the habit of looking up your error messages. They're quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Mad Physicist is right, the problem is serial port stays open. When i try to re-run the program it tries to open a port which is already open.

After adding a CloseSerial function in my library and calling it on the example, the problem solved.

```
#File name iDealibrary.py
def CloseSerial():
    ser.close()

#File name example.py
iDealibrary.ConnectIdeaLab()
iDealibrary.CloseSerial()
```